# How to get round value if value is in decimal in php?

Tags: php

```
$str = 6.87;    
$x = ceil($str/5) * 5;
echo $x;
```

I have a variable `str` and I want to covert `str` round value. In above I have `6.87` and I want `6.9` and if I have `6.43` then it should be `6.4` similarly if `$str = 6.45` then it become `6.5`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Have you looked at `round()`?

Comment: Yes but it round whole value like if `6.87` then it give `7` @NigelRen

Comment: @steave Have you looked at the documentation of [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)? You can pass the precision as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be more like this.. the 1 being number of position(s) to round up to.

```
$str = 6.87;
echo(round($str,1));
```

which will give you 6.9

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$str = 6.87;    
echo round($str,1);
```

where the first parameter is the variable, then the second is the decimal point to round.

this will output

`6.9`

Answer (score 0):

You should use round() with 2nd parameter 1 like following code :

```
echo $str = round(6.45,1);
```

Output:

```
6.5
```

Comment: The second parameter is *The optional number of decimal digits to round to*, true just happens to be treated as 1 so it works more by accident than design.